# Rust parsing string to usize always returns error

Tags: rust

I am trying to make tic tac toe with rust and have this chunk of code:

```rust
print!("Enter a square: ");
loop {
    io::stdout().flush().expect("Flush Error");

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Input Error");

    let option_num: Option<usize> = match input.parse() {
        Ok(value) => Some(value),
        Err(_e) => Option::None
    };

    if option_num == None {
        print!("Invalid input. Try again: ");
        continue;
    }
```

Explanation:
First we take the user's input.
Then we convert it to a number so that we can use it to find which square to place the X or O in.
If the input is not a number, The user is informed.
Otherwise some other code is run which I have not included

When I run it, I never reach the if statement because the parsing always returns an error, even if the input is a number

I am new to rust and have no idea why this is happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: Incase it's not clear why this was listed as a duplicate, it's because the string includes the trailing `\n`, which can be removed by calling `str::trim` before calling `parse`

Comment: By the way, if you want to convert a `Result<T, E>` into `Option<T>`, you can do that conveniently with `Result::ok()` (
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok):

```let option_num = input.trim().parse::<usize>().ok();```

However, why not operate with the Result type directly?